# Adding all promises without a tracker option to a global promise tracker in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I wish to add all promises without a specified tracker property to a global promise-tracker and use that to initialise a spinner if the app is busy for > 200ms. So far I have tried altering the angular-promise-tracker source code to add an else statement and I have tried adding a promise tracker to $rootscope but I seem to be missing something. **Edit** - I also tried decorating $q but ran into a circular dependency error as the angular-promise-tracker relies on $q.

Is there a preferred method to achieve this functionality? Can anyone help me out? I didn't want to raise an issue on the project page (https://github.com/ajoslin/angular-promise-tracker/) as it's more a request for guidance

Comment: The basic approach I would try is: use a decorator for `$q` to monkey patch `$q.defer()` to instead create a tracked promise, saving the existing `$q.defer()` as `$q._defer()`. Then use another decorator for `promiseTracker` to replace their function with your own that calls theirs, and replaces the `.createPromise()` function with something that temporarily restores `$q.defer` to the original one, calls their `.createPromise()` and then puts your `$q.defer` replacement back. If that makes any sense at all. I just don't have time now to do this fully.

Comment: Decorating $q was my first attempt but I ran into circular dependency as the promisetracker relies on $q, updated question I forgot about this

Comment: @LinuxN00b: can you post your attempt with code?

Comment: Did you make any progress with this? I am trying to do the same thing.